# Why is this language regular?

Tags: automata, automated-theorem-proving

I'm at the beginning of Theoretical Informatics and I was given some tasks one of which is following...

> Be $k\in \mathbb{N}$, show that following language $L$ with the
> alphabet $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$ is regular.
>
> $L= \{w\mid w$ is $2k$ Symbols long and a Palindrome$\}$

In books and on the Internet the consensus is gernerally that Palindromes are not regular (reason is that Finite Machines can't remember much information) but here I am asked to prove it, therefore it should be true.

Why is that ? In my mind I found it impossible to construct a (Non-deterministic) Finite Machine with that properties.

Can someone give me a hint why this is true ?

Comment: You are given a fixed length for the palindrome. For each $k$, the corresponding language $L$ is finite and hence regular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't contradict the fact that the set of all palindromes is not a regular language, as you are given a fixed length for the palindrome. For each $k$, the corresponding language $L$ is finite and hence regular. If we write $L_k$ rather than $L$ to make the dependency on $k$ explicit, the union $\bigcup_k L_k$ is not a regular language, but each $L_k$ is.

Comment: OK I get that. Can you give me Tips or literature that teaches me how to prove that? I can't just write that I can make a DA for every case (since the language is finite), can I?

Comment: You can show by induction on the length of a finite language, that any finite language is regular. The inductive proof will give you an algorithm that constructs a DA to recognise each finite language.

Comment: True. Thanks I lot for your help!